# No Database selected when executing MySQL in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems with this php code which needs to create a table in the database specified by the user.  But whenever I try to execute the SQL it tells me no database selected.  My code is as follow

```
<?php  
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","peter")
or die('Error connecting to mysql'); // Check connection  
// Create table 
mysql_select_db("USE Ebooks");//Select Database

$foldername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['foldername']);//Obtain Folder Name 

$sql = sprintf("CREATE TABLE %s (ID CHAR(3) ,Books CHAR(30))", $foldername);  
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_close($con);  
?>
```

Comment: if you are new to php and mysql, then get off on the right foot and don't use mysql_, use mysqli_ or pdo routines

Comment: You should not create a different table for each folder, you should have a folder table and a book table instead. Plus, drop this code as it is vulnerable and deprecated, and move to widely accepted solutions as PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
mysql_select_db( "Ebooks" ) or die( 'Error'. mysql_error() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
mysql_select_db("Ebooks");//Select Database
```

Comment: @user2420874 - Hi new user welcome to stackoverflow here people support each other.One with answer another with accepting and voting answers and comments